# How to compile *.sln of visual studio 2019 to run on another PC?

Tags: c++, build, compilation, visual-studio-2019, static-linking

I created a program using "visual studio 2019" (using MariaDB and Qt).

I tried the static compilation as follows

1. Under Configuration Properties --> General, change the "Use of MFC" field to "Use MFC in a Static Library".
2. Under Configuration Properties --> C/C++ --> Code Generation, change the "Runtime Library" field to "Multi-Threaded (/MT)"

The exe file that compiled this program works normally on my PC.
But when I run it on another PC, the error message below will be printed out.

1. There are no DLL files* related to Qt and mariadb, so it cannot be executed.

- are libmariadb.dll, Qt5Cored.dll, Qt5Guid.dll, Qt5Widgetsd.dll.

In order to solve this problem, the DLL file needed was executed with the same path as the EXE file. As a result, the following error message is displayed:
3. "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)"

---

Q1. As far as I know, if I do a static compilation, I can run it on another computer even if I only have the exe file. However, I get an error message saying that the DLL file is missing. Is there something wrong with my static compilation method?

Q2. The error message "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)" occurs even though I have provided the necessary DLL files.

I'd really appreciate if you could tell me how to solve this. Thank you for reading this long article.

Comment: The alternative is to deploy your executable with all depending DLLs of Qt and what else is needed. Qt has a tool for this but you can assemble this in the file explorer as well. Do you have anything in mind to build a setup executable for your application?

Comment: Btw. `Qt5Cored.dll, Qt5Guid.dll, Qt5Widgetsd.dll` looks to me like you want to deploy your Debug build. That's bad (if not even prohibited) for security and other reasons. For deploy, you should use release builds always. (Concerning "prohibited": To deploy something built in Visual Studio with MSVC, you get also dependencies to the MSVC runtime DLLs. MS offers a package `vcredist` or so which you can bundle with your application. This is available for release builds only, and the web site states that this is very intentional.)

Comment: In order to solve this problem, the DLL file needed was executed with the same path as the EXE file. As a result, the following error message is displayed: 3. "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)"

Comment: How can i build using "release build"??

Comment: Visual Studio has an option menu for this (in the top tool bar) - left of the green arrow to run the application.

Comment: FYI: [Qt for Windows - Deployment](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html)

Comment: I used "release" to build, and I tried running it on another PC. This time, however, a message occurred that there was no DLL file* as follows:
 * are Qt5Widgets.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Core.dll

Comment: You still have to provide the DLLs together with your executable. That's why a lot of applications provide an installation program - a setup...exe or something similar. This is basically a (compressed) archive of all needed files but may perform additional steps like adding/modifying registry entries or what ever else might be necessary to setup an application correctly.

Comment: And btw. Qt5Widgets.dll, Qt5Gui.dll, Qt5Core.dll may (or may not) have dependencies to other DLLs themselves. The above link mentions a free tool "Dependency Walker" which I can recommend to find out about all dependencies of your executable.

Comment: "Use of MFC" is just for Microsoft's framework library, Not used at all if you instead use Qt. You also need to link against static Qt libraries to avoid references to its DLLs.

Comment: @BoP i provided the DLL files. However, the following error message still occurs: "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)"

Comment: @Scheff'sCat i provided the DLL files. However, the following error message still occurs: "The Application Was Unable to Start (0xc000007b)"

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Thanks to your help, I solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem following step:

1. build using "Release"
2. deploy using "windeployqt.exe"
3. execute "vc_redist.x64.exe"(the output file of step 2)